# import big libraries without increase app size - objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode5, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I'm new to Objective C.

I have to add many big libraries to my xcode project, but finally my app stopped due to memory pressure.  The memory usage reached 200M.

How can I add these libraries without effect on app size?

I read something about static and shared libraries,  Can anyone explain them to me?  Also can this help me?

Thank you.

Comment: A static library's memory is allocated separately for each process that uses it.  A shared library's memory is allocated once, for the first process that uses it, and any subsequent process that uses it calls the code present in the already-allocated memory.  And yes, this should be able to help.  Is that clear enough?

Comment: Thank you , but i want to know how can i put library as a static for only process or shared ? And how that can help me ?, I add frameworks with big size and copy them in destination folder project. , Are libraries deffirent than frameworks in adding ?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  What are you asking?

Comment: Are these big libraries in Copy Bundle Resources?

Comment: Sorry for late, I use frameworks like Facebook, Google+, Parse ... etc, and they have a big size, my question in simple way, How can I add them and use without increase my app size very mush ?

Comment: I add them in Frameworks folder in Xcode project, and copy them in project folder destination, I think that is a wrong way to import.

Comment: @user306481, app memory usage and app size are two different concerns. What is the size of .ipa file? Also in the question, "The memory usage reached 200M." how you discovered it?

Comment: @vladof, Thank you, ipa size is 15MB nearly, and I knew that memory reached 200M from "Debug Navigator" and clicked on Memory tab and curve in "Memory Utilized" reached to 200M and more, I follow code and discovered that this line when comment it,  every this go very good: sign in to google plus, but i don't know why ?, i used it before without any problems.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's wrong without knowing code. Why not try profile the app in Instruments Activity Monitor, Memory Leak. Run some tests and examine what is causing unexpected memory usage.

Comment: Thank you @vladof, it was bad handle of google plus sign in code, i didn't know how can it do this memory bug, specially cuz i used it in another project before and works, every thing now is good, Thank you again.